# ARKit distance between eyes

Tags: ios, swift, computer-vision, arkit

Hello guys I'm trying to integrate Vision framework to detect a face and keep track of both eyes, then I'm trying to measure the distance between the center of both eyes in a face detected by Vision. My problem at the moment is how to get this distance in the real world based on the two points for the center of the eye that Vision gave to me. After the face is recognised I use the following code to calculate the distance between the center of the eyes

```
guard let sceneView = self.view as? ARSKView, let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame else {
                return
            }
            let w = face.boundingBox.size.width * image.size.width
            let h = face.boundingBox.size.height * image.size.height
            let x = face.boundingBox.origin.x * image.size.width
            let y = face.boundingBox.origin.y * image.size.height
            // left pupil
                context?.saveGState()
                context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.yellow.cgColor)
                var leftIrisLocation = CGPoint()
                if let landmark = face.landmarks?.leftPupil {
                    for i in 0...landmark.pointCount - 1 { // last point is 0,0
                        let point = landmark.normalizedPoints[i]
                        if i == 0 {
                            leftIrisLocation = CGPoint(x: x + CGFloat(point.x) * w, y: y + CGFloat(point.y) * h)
                            context?.move(to: leftIrisLocation)
                            context?.addEllipse(in: CGRect(origin: leftIrisLocation, size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)))
                        }
                    }
                }
                context?.closePath()
                context?.setLineWidth(8.0)
                context?.drawPath(using: .stroke)
                context?.saveGState()

                // right pupil
                context?.saveGState()
                context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.yellow.cgColor)
                var rightIrisLocation = CGPoint()
                if let landmark = face.landmarks?.rightPupil {
                    for i in 0...landmark.pointCount - 1 { // last point is 0,0
                        let point = landmark.normalizedPoints[i]
                        if i == 0 {
                            rightIrisLocation = CGPoint(x: x + CGFloat(point.x) * w, y: y + CGFloat(point.y) * h)
                            context?.move(to: rightIrisLocation)
                            context?.addEllipse(in: CGRect(origin: rightIrisLocation, size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)))
                        }
                    }
                }
                let distanceFromIris = self.distanceFrom(p1: leftIrisLocation, to: rightIrisLocation)
```

At this point I have the distance on the image but no the real world distance, so I try to hitTest on the current frame to get the distance from each eye to the camera and then calculate the final distance using pythagoras theorem as following:

```
       for leftResult in currentFrame.hitTest(leftIrisLocation, types: [.featurePoint, .existingPlaneUsingExtent]) {
            print("Distance left iris to camera")
            print(leftResult.distance)
        }

        for rightResult in currentFrame.hitTest(rightIrisLocation, types: [.featurePoint, .existingPlaneUsingExtent]) {
            print("Distance right iris to camera")
            print(rightResult.distance)
        }

        let distanceBetweenIris = sqrt((leftResult.distance * leftResult.distance) - (rightResult.distance * rightResult.distance))
```

But this `distanceBetweenIris` is getting really big like 20cm where it should be close to 5cm ~ 6cm, any ideas how to reduce this big error?

Comment: There are two incorrect assumptions here: 1) an AR hit test does not precisely find real-world objects, so you're not getting actual distance to the eyes... at best you're getting the distance to some computationally-interesting point in the image within several cm of each hit test.

Comment: 2) Even assuming you had distances from the camera to each eye, the triangle formed by those three points is not a right triangle, so the Pythagorean theorem won't find you the length of the third side. See the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) instead. (Sorry, comments instead of an answer because I don't have a great way forward to suggest.)